# UWP Re-launch list of applications

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a list of five applications I want to launch. Whenever the user tries to exit out of any of the applications, I want the application to automatically launch again. This is my code so far:

```
    void restartApplication()
    {
        foreach (var i in procs)
        {
            if (!i.HasExited)
            {
                i.WaitForExit();
                i.Start();
            }
        }
        restartApplication();
    }
```

And this is the code to launch the appplications as a process:

```
                var start = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                    FileName = filename,
                    Arguments = arg
                };
                myProcess = new Process { StartInfo = start };
                procs.Add(myProcess); 
                myProcess.Start();
```

The problem with this is that I have to close the applications in the order that they appear in procs for them to restart. So if I close the third application first it won't restart. How do I fix this?

Comment: Hello, does your code belong to UWP? If so, can you provide some more complete code snippets? UWP applications usually do not interfere with the life cycle of other applications.

Comment: Yes it is a UWP. I have updated my question.

Comment: Hello, is the application you created is a Win32 application converted from Desktop-Bridge (this also call the UWP)? `Process` is usually not used in UWP to start other applications. Can you explain the purpose of this, it may be achieved by other methods, such as `Launcher.LaunchUriAsync()` to launch other UWP applications through [Uri scheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/uri-schemes)

Comment: The application reads from a config.json file to determine which application to launch. I can't use Launcher.LaunchUriAsync because this application has to run any application, not just apps with a registered protocol.

Comment: Hello, UWP currently does not have permission to launch any other application. In terms of design, UWP applications cannot directly interfere with the life cycle of other applications. You can try to create win32 solution